# Changing the signature on a cert or creating a key file from an existing cert

Tags: openssl

I would like to create a certificate with a specific public key. I have another certificate which contains the public key I need to use, and I wish to change the signature on that certificate to a root CA of my making.

I know how to get a hex representation of the public key, but OpenSSL wants an encoded file as input when creating signed certificates.

How can I provide OpenSSL with the input public key file it needs in order to create a new certificate, when I only have an existing certificate which is signed by a different CA?

Comment: What's the use of announcing a public key when you don't have the private key?

Answer (score 3):

It's a rather odd capability but OpenSSL commandline can indeed "re-sign" an existing cert.

```
 openssl x509 -in oldcert -CA cacertfile [-CAkey capkeyfile] -out newcert -days N
```

CA cert and privatekey must (both) be in PEM format; you can include the privatekey in the cert file and omit the `-CAkey file` option. If you omit `-days N` validity defaults to 30 days. oldcert and newcert are PEM by default, but can be changed with `-inform` and `-outform` respectively.

If you are only doing this once, it's easiest to use `-set_serial S` for the new **serial**. If you will or might do this multiple times for one CA, to ensure each one gets a unique serial let OpenSSL use its serial-counter file by specifying `-CAcreateserial` on the first one at least.

By default **extensions** are left unchanged. If oldcert has an AuthorityKeyIdentifier extension pointing to the old CA, and the new CA is different, this will make the resulting certificate unusable because it can't be validated. Other CA-related extensions like CRLDP and AIA may also cause problems. Use `-clrext` to remove the old extensions; if you do need (any) extensions in the new cert, you must configure them (all) in a file specified with `-extfile` and optionally `-extensions` (section).

See https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html#SIGNING-OPTIONS (and follow the link to x509v3_config if you need extensions). The warning under `-CA` "... without the -req option the input ... must be selfsigned" is overstated; if not openssl gives an error message about "unable to verify", but does create the new cert as desired. Also, release **1.0.1 before f had a bug** that causes this case to produce wrong output; make sure you don't use one of those versions.

And as already noted unless you have the matching privatekey somewhere (possibly on a different system/app/whatever) the resulting cert is of very limited utility.